# Find closest input and set value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On select value change I want find closest input by class and change value.

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#doc_service').on('change', function (){

            $.getJSON('\/services\/search-service', {id: $(this).val()}, function(data){

                $(this).closest('.price').val(data);

               //$('.price').val(data);


            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

My code `$(this).closest('.price').val(data);` not changing value, I try `$('.price').val(data);` it's work, but I have many input and want change value only one closest. Structure `html` is `table`

**HTML**

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <select id="doc_service">
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="price">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <select id="doc_service">
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="price">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Your HTML is also required. The `closest()` method is meant for selecting parent elements, which is probably not what you're looking to do.

Comment: 'this' doesn't refer to '#doc_service', since you are inside a jquery block. If you want to read more, this article may give u a start ->  http://blog.millermedeiros.com/avoiding-the-this-keyword-on-jquery/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` in your code doesn't refer to the changed element, you should cache the object. Also note that `closest` method only selects the closest matching parent element.

```
$('#doc_service').on('change', function (){
    var _this = this;
    $.getJSON('\/services\/search-service', {id: this.value }, function(data) {
        $(_this).closest('td').next().find('.price').val(data);
    });
});
```

And IDs must be unique, `$('#doc_service')` only selects the first matching element, here classes should be used instead.

Comment: I find it hard to believe the OP has an input field as an ancestor of the `'#doc_service'` element.

Comment: @Boaz Yes, of course. inputs can't have descendant elements. Didn't notice that. Thanks.

Comment: +1 Now that we have the markup, the OP and the answer are making sense.